# How do I double my step variable for each for-loop iteration in Python 3?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm new to Python, and I'm playing around with recursive functions just for practice.

I made the following algorithm which takes a number as *x* and halves it until it is equal to 1. *n* is the number of times *x* has been halved.

```
def binary(x, n = 0):
    print(n,":",x)
    x = x // 2
    n += 1
    if x > 0:
       binary(x, n)
       return x
    return x
```

I'm trying to make a loop that will call binary() with multiple values for x. I want my step to be doubled each iteration. I have it working with a while loop like the one below.

```
i = 1
while i < 1000000000:
    print("when x is", i, ":")
    binary(i)
    i += i
```

For some reason though, I can't seem to achieve the same thing with a For loop. Here's what I have now.

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    print("when x is", i, ":")
    binary(i)
    i += i
```

In the code above, `i += i` does not seem to effect the `i` in my header. I know that range() takes a third parameter called step, but I've tried this:

```
for i in range(1,1000, i += i):
    # statements
```

This gives me a name error, and says "i is not defined".
Most of my experience with programming is in JavaScript and C#. In both of those languages I wouldn't of had any trouble doing this.

How would I get this to work in a For loop using Python 3?

Comment: what is the point of your recursive call, you’re not doing anything with the returned value. Shouldn't you write `return binary(x,n)` instead in your `if`?

Comment: The trouble is that for loop in those languages is secretly a while loop.  As with most languages with some c heritage.  For loop in Python is in fact a foreach loop.  There are completely different and the only two things they have in common is the name and the fact that they are used for looping.  Pretending they are or should be the same is a recipe for mental illness.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yes I should write `return binary(x,n)` and I also don't need `return x` outside of my `if` now that I look at it. There's no real "point" to this recursion. Like I said I was just messing around for practice. What stumped me was using a for loop in a way that I'm used to doing in other languages.

Comment: @MiroslavFranc This makes a lot of sense. Thinking of them in this way will save me some headaches down the road. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range) is indeed step. But you should use it with a computed value like:

```
for i in range(1,1000,2):
    #statements
```

The reason why your `i += i` didn't worked is because, under the hood, the for-loop is executing something similar to `i = next(...)` at the end of an iteration, overiding your last increment.

### Edit

You can achieve the desired effect using a generator, but it kinda kills the "trying to avoid while-loops" thing:

```
def myrange(start, stop):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += i

for i in myrange(1, 1000):
    print(i)
```

Anyway, while-loops are perfectly valid constructs and I’d personnally go with one in this case. Do not forget that the for-loop has a rather different semantic in python than in both languages you’re used to. So trying to use a for-loop because you are able to do so with javascript seems like a bad idea if all what you need is a while-loop.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the answer I needed. Python is strange to what I'm used to doing. So far I've only used for loops for iterating lists, so I sort of thought they worked the same as I've used before. Guess I'll just go with the while loop for situations like this.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`range` can step by a fixed amount, but not a variable amount. Use a `while-loop` to increment `i` by `i`:

```
i += i
```

---

You could replace the `while-loop` with an iterator, such as:

```
import itertools as IT
for i in (2**i for i in IT.count()):
    if i >= 1000000000: break
    print("when x is", i, ":")
    binary(i)
```

but I don't think this has any advantage over a simple `while-loop`.

Comment: I feel like you could achieve it with a for loop, but it'd mean doing stuff that's kind of bs with generators. :P

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is doubling `i`, then why not just raise it to the power?

```
for p in range(int(1000000000**0.5)):
    print(binary(2**p)
```